# Unread variables in a program with only if/else statements

Tags: theory

Given a program with only if/else statements is it then possible to decide which variables that occur but never read?

Comment: If the program ONLY contains if/else statements, what would be inside of them?

Comment: By "occur but never read" do you mean "are modified/initialized but never accessed"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Given a program with only if/else statements [assuming no branches backwards and loops], there is a finite number of paths in the program.

You can check all of them, check which conditions must be met in order to get to each path, and find contradictions [un accessable paths], and this way to find which variables are never used.

This can be implemented as a simpler version of [Hoare logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoare_logic), which is pretty simple to automatize, without loops. [with loops it is of course impossible to automatize it]

Comment: Thank you! Just what I needed to hear.

Answer (score 0):

You could place trace, or debugging statements in the specific if blocks, like

```
if (assertion) 
{
    // print or echo or var_dump etc..
} 
else if(assertion) 
{
    // print or echo or var_dump etc..
} 
else if(assertion) 
{
    // print or echo or var_dump etc..
}
```

If you can trace the code this way, you can assert any variable or code within the block would be executed/read.

Comment: I think the OP means there is also an input to the program... And how will you decide which inputs to activate the program on in order to cover all accessable paths?